# TypeScript strictNullChecks - Object is possibly 'null'

Tags: angular, typescript2.0

After enabling `strictNullChecks` with Angular 4.1.1, getting several errors for `null` checks. I have fixed bundles of them but unable to fix the same `Object is possibly 'null'` for `this.form.get('username').value`. Likewise others, I have tried the same but unable to fix the error.

```
if (this.form.get('username') != null) {
    body.append('username', this.form.get('username').value);
}
```

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Try using [Non-null assertion operator](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What%27s-new-in-TypeScript#non-null-assertion-operator) like

```
this.form.get('username')!.value; // notice !
```

Comment: Linter forbids this and he should be right. Any other idea?

Comment: Here is the link to the palantir rule: https://palantir.github.io/tslint/rules/no-non-null-assertion/

Answer (score 3):

You really don't need to cast here. You actually never have to.

The most compact way to do it:

```
const username = this.form.get('username');
if (username) body.append('username', username.value);
```

Or in exit-early style:

```
const username = this.form.get('username');
if (!username) return;
# back to normal flow
body.append('username', username.value); // no complaint, username cannot be falsy, then it must be { value: string }
```

The compiler cannot infer that `this.form.get('username')` hasn't change between the `null` check and the time you use `.value` on it.

With a `const` variable, it can.